# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deon_deletefault'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

hello I am trying to run a project with python 3.8 and django 3.1.7 and I get the following error:

Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  
  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  
 File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
 
 File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]

  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()

  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()

  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/entornos/red/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  
  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/RedDebate/reddebate/resumen/models.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Debate(models.Model):

  File "/home/mauricio/Escritorio/RedDebate/reddebate/resumen/models.py", line 25, in Debate
    args_max = models.IntegerField(deon_deletefault=1)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deon_deletefault'
```

I send you the code that is associated with the error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import *
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
import unicodedata

# Create your models here.
class Debate(models.Model):
    #parametros de la tabla.
    id_debate = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    owner_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='username')
    length = models.IntegerField(default=300, blank=True)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='open')
    args_max = models.IntegerField(deon_deletefault=1)
    position_max = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    counterargs_max = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    counterargs_type = models.IntegerField(default=0) # 0:ambas # 1: contraria
    members_type = models.IntegerField(default=0) #0 debate publico
    participation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='all')
    img = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, default="RDdefault.png")

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self): # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return self.title
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
    def as_dict(self):
        return {'text': self.text, 'type':self.members_type, 'id':self.id_debate}
```

Comment: What do you expect `deon_deletefault` to do?

Comment: mmm I don't know friend, they asked me to run it alone. In general terms it is a web application to discuss

Comment: @KlausD. deon_default  It is the argument presented by the user who is creating a new topic for discussion, by default it will only be able to present a single argument

Comment: `deon_default` is neither `deon_deletefault` nor `default`.

Comment: I believe this is a typo. `deon_deletefault` is `on_delete` inserted into `default` (I believe you wanted to write `default`)...

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work   @AbdulAzizBarkat